# MongoDB count and get the limited data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pagination, mongodb-query

I'm trying to get the count all the data for the query and as well as get the limited data (for pagination) but both the console output gives me the count. 
What is that I'm doing wrong.
Pls help

```
const curFind = fbUser.find(find, 'firstName gender age birthday facebookId profileURL email imageUrl preferences blocked flames likes rejects location reported')

  curFind.count(function(e, count) {
    console.log(count);
    curFind.skip(0).limit(10).hint( { $natural : 1 } ).exec(function(err, data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print the `curFind` object before and after executing `count`, you will notice that the `Query` object's `op` field changes from `find` to `count`. It may or may not be a bug with mongoose, but explains why you are getting a count again. I generally don't re-use the query object - which would solve your issue too.